# New action bar not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

From number of days I have been trying to show a new action bar. By this I mean that I want add colors and a new icon etc but I have not yet been successful. Below is my code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.reach2employee"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />        

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Employer Registration"
       >            
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Employer Login"          
        ></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Forgot Password"
        ></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".PostJobActivity"
        android:label="Post Job"
        ></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".SearchJobActivity"
        android:label="Search Job"
        ></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".JobsActivity"
        android:label="All Jobs"
        ></activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".JobDetailActivity"
        android:label="Job Detail"
        ></activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**menu_before_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
      android:id="@+id/item1" 
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Refresh"
 ></item>
<item 
      android:id="@+id/item2" 
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Overflow"
 ></item>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
package com.reach2employee;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {               

Button registerBtn;
Button loginBtn;
Button logoutBtn;
Button shareApp;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = Common.myPreferencesStr;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

    sharedpreferences   =   getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();                          

    registerBtn     =   (Button)findViewById(R.id.registrationBtn);
    loginBtn        =   (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);            
    logoutBtn       =   (Button)findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
    shareApp        =   (Button)findViewById(R.id.shareApp);

    if(sharedpreferences.contains("userId")){
        registerBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loginBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        logoutBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        registerBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logoutBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_before_login, menu);      
    return true;        
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void shareThisAppFun(View view){
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.sendThisApp)));
}

public void goToRegistrationPage(View view){        
    Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class,0);
}

public void goToLoginPage(View view){       
    Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class,1);
}

public void goToPostAJobActivity(View view){        
    Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,PostJobActivity.class,1);
}

public void goToSearchPage(View view){      
    Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,SearchJobActivity.class,0);
}

public void goToAllJobsPage(View view){
    //Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,JobsActivity.class,0);

    Intent intent   =   new Intent(this,JobsActivity.class);        
    intent.putExtra("fromPage", "allJobs");                         
    startActivity(intent);

}   
public void logoutBtnClickFun(View view){

    //First clear Session
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    Common.moveToAnotherActivity(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class,1);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.reach2employee.MainActivity" >           
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/appLogoRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
   >       
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/appLogo"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:src="@drawable/onlyitemployees_logo"
   />           
</LinearLayout>    
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/appShortDescRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
    >                   
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/appTaglineDesc"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/appTaglineDescStr" 
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:textStyle="italic"
       android:gravity="center"
       />         
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/appShortDesc"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/appShortDesc"
       android:gravity="center" 
       />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/appShortDesc1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/appShortDesc1"
       android:gravity="center" 
       />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/appShortDesc2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/appShortDesc2"
       android:gravity="center" 
       />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchBtnRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareApp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sendThisApp"
        android:background="#D08B3A"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="shareThisAppFun"                       
     />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allJobsBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/allJobsBtnText"
        android:background="#D08B3A"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="goToAllJobsPage"                       
     />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/searchBtnText"
        android:background="#b93983"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="goToSearchPage"             
        />            

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/postVacancyBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/postVacancyBtnText"
        android:background="#9f2c35"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="goToPostAJobActivity"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />       

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registrationBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/registrationBtnText"
        android:background="#8eb534"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="goToRegistrationPage"
     /> 
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loginBtnText"
        android:background="#3795BD"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="goToLoginPage"
     />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logoutBtnText"
        android:background="#3795BD"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="logoutBtnClickFun"
     />

</LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

**In MainActivity.java, I tried to extend Activity but that also did not work.**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why my custom or new action bar is not showing?

Comment: You never set an Action Bar in your onCreate. Could you post your activity_main.xml?

Comment: @AdamS I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Apologies, I've been working with a Toolbar for a while now. Action Bars work differently; the answer asking about what your theme extends is likely the correct path to follow.

Comment: "By this I mean that I want add colors and a new icon etc but I have not yet been successful" -- please point out **precisely** where in the above wall of code you think that you have anything that will "add colors and a new icon".

Answer (score 1):

What is your AppTheme? Check in res/values/styles (Android Studio):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Some styles, like the one shown, include actionbar automatically (even for Extends Activity). Not sure which other themes, as I'm an Android newbie.

Comment: I have updated my question and added styles.xml in it.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the error text.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your **menu_before_login.xml** file :

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Your xml file should look something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

</menu>
```

Hope this helps you.